# oval of FSM diagram represent what?

Tags: finite-state-machine

I am reading a document of Varnish and I get the important [VCL state image](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_LUDOT42CYEM/TQarLT6uu_I/AAAAAAAAACA/pbbKqhPmpe4/s320/varnish+2.1.x+finite+state+machine.jpg) shown below.

We know we often use UML as a standard to draw a state machine.

but this image is not, is it follow another standard? or not?

I can understand the `start/end` diagram (hexagon), state diagram(two rectangle), judgement condition(rhombus),

but I don't understand what the oval represents, please tell me.

[image]

Comment: see [Should a question that is meaningless without viewing an external link be closed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266909/839601)

Comment: Why you say my question is meaningless?  its about state machine.

Comment: This is not a state chart, it is a flowchart.

Comment: Looks like it was drawn using graphviz.

Comment: @ErikEidt I think it's close enough.  The author seems to think it's one.

Comment: @JimmyJames, yes, we often confuse one with the other.  (Flowcharts have decisions, state charts have transitions.)

Comment: @ErikEidt Right and this has both, no?

Comment: Have a look at "lookup" between "recv" and "hash": flow step or state transition?  (yes, your right, its a hodgepodge..)

Comment: I'm so sorry about this image, I given the wrong FSM. now I have updated my post.

Comment: This is the Varnish finite state machine, https://book.varnish-software.com/4.0/chapters/VCL_Basics.html#figure-23 per the documentation found here https://book.varnish-software.com/4.0/chapters/VCL_Basics.html

Comment: The fact that there are different types of symbols in the picture shown in the question is indicative of it not being a finite state machine. Finite state machines only have two things, states and transitions.

Answer (score 0):

The ovals are the 'states' in the finite *state* machine.